# Obtaining CPU descriptions on Mac OS X

Tags: macos

I'd like to programmatically get the CPU descriptions on Mac OS X, which look something like this:

```
Intel(R) Core(TM)2 CPU 6700 @ 2.66GHz
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X5550 @ 2.67GHz
```

On Linux you can do `grep "^model name" /proc/cpuinfo` and on Windows you can look at the `ProcessorNameString` value in `HKLM\Hardware\Description\System\CentralProcessor\0` in the registry, but how do you get that information on OS X?

Comment: Not sure it matters too much, but I'm using C++.  If there's some system call (e.g. `sysctlbyname()`) I can make or a (pseudo-) file to look at that would be good.

Comment: The command `/usr/sbin/system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | grep "Processor Name"` does give _something_, but not the full string: `Intel Core 2 Duo`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can pass `machdep.cpu.brand_string` to sysctl to retrieve the string you're looking for.

```
[ben@imac ~]$ sysctl machdep.cpu.brand_string
machdep.cpu.brand_string: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2400S CPU @ 2.50GHz
```

The same information is exposed through the `sysctl(3)` functions.

```
[ben@imac ~]$ cat sys.c
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char buf[100];
    size_t buflen = 100;
    sysctlbyname("machdep.cpu.brand_string", &buf, &buflen, NULL, 0);

    printf("%s\n", buf);
}

[ben@imac ~]$ ./sys
Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2400S CPU @ 2.50GHz
```

Comment: Still works like charm on macOS 12.1, including the M1 systems!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200103164013/https://osxbook.com/book/src/).  There's a file in the downloaded source called processor_info.c (and a ton of other good stuff) that I'm pretty sure will give you this information.

Comment: The code examples in `processor_info.c` (in 7-6 and 7-7) do give some information on the CPUs, but unfortunately not the description string.  Also the code calls `mach_host_self()`, which seems to need root privileges :-(.