# How can I get the iOS device CPU architecture in runtime

Tags: ios, objective-c, cpu-architecture

Is there a way to identify the iOS device CPU architecture in runtime?

Thank you.

Comment: Try to set defines for device models: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197509/ios-iphone-get-device-model-and-make

Comment: Thank you but I think I wasn't clear, or maybe I mislead the question, that is fine as far as it detects the model, how can I get if it's ARMv6, ARM, ARMv7, i386?

Comment: Hmmm I think I get what you mean, I should get the model and set defines due to the model to find the architecture.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use sysctlbyname :

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>
#include <mach/machine.h>

NSString *getCPUType(void)
{
    NSMutableString *cpu = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    size_t size;
    cpu_type_t type;
    cpu_subtype_t subtype;
    size = sizeof(type);
    sysctlbyname("hw.cputype", &type, &size, NULL, 0);

    size = sizeof(subtype);
    sysctlbyname("hw.cpusubtype", &subtype, &size, NULL, 0);

    // values for cputype and cpusubtype defined in mach/machine.h
    if (type == CPU_TYPE_X86)
    {
            [cpu appendString:@"x86 "];
             // check for subtype ...

    } else if (type == CPU_TYPE_ARM)
    {
            [cpu appendString:@"ARM"];
            switch(subtype)
            {
                    case CPU_SUBTYPE_ARM_V7:
                    [cpu appendString:@"V7"];
                    break;
                    // ...
            }
    }
    return [cpu autorelease];
}
```

Comment: For iPhone 5s device or later, most devices support 64bit and we could add CPU_TYPE_ARM64 as a new case for type & subtype.

Comment: @Emmanuel thank you for the answer. But I want to know if we can get the name of the processor like "Intel i5"

Comment: @VikasBansal Hi, using sysctlbyname with "machdep.cpu.brand_string" should give you what you want. [Here a complete answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650659/obtaining-cpu-descriptions-on-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 14):

I think this is the better way,

```
#import <mach-o/arch.h>

NXArchInfo *info = NXGetLocalArchInfo();
NSString *typeOfCpu = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:info->description];
//typeOfCpu = "arm64 v8"
```

Comment: How to translate this in swift ?

Comment: Works perfectly for me (I think this is the best solution in 2020...). Thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

Just adding more to @Emmanuel's answer:

```
- (NSString *)getCPUType {
      NSMutableString *cpu = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
      size_t size;
      cpu_type_t type;
      cpu_subtype_t subtype;
      size = sizeof(type);
      sysctlbyname("hw.cputype", &type, &size, NULL, 0);

      size = sizeof(subtype);
      sysctlbyname("hw.cpusubtype", &subtype, &size, NULL, 0);

      // values for cputype and cpusubtype defined in mach/machine.h
      if (type == CPU_TYPE_X86_64) {
          [cpu appendString:@"x86_64"];
      } else if (type == CPU_TYPE_X86) {
          [cpu appendString:@"x86"];
      } else if (type == CPU_TYPE_ARM) {
          [cpu appendString:@"ARM"];
          switch(subtype)
          {
              case CPU_SUBTYPE_ARM_V6:
                  [cpu appendString:@"V6"];
                  break;
              case CPU_SUBTYPE_ARM_V7:
                  [cpu appendString:@"V7"];
                  break;
              case CPU_SUBTYPE_ARM_V8:
                  [cpu appendString:@"V8"];
                  break;
          }
      }
      return cpu; 
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! You're answer is missing CPU_TYPE_ARM64 type checking which can be followed by subtype checking for CPU_SUBTYPE_ARM64_V8 (currently it will always be V8, but might change in future)

Answer (score 4):

Here is the swift version of @Mahmut's answer.

```swift
import MachO

private func getArchitecture() -> NSString {
    let info = NXGetLocalArchInfo()
    return NSString(utf8String: (info?.pointee.description)!)!
}

print(getArchitecture() ?? "No architecture found")
```

### Results

- iPhone 12: `ARM64E` [What is ARM64E?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52624308/xcode-arm64-vs-arm64e)
- Mac Mini M1

  - iOS 13 emulator: `Intel 80486`
  - iOS 14 emulator: `ARM64E`
- MacBook Pro 16" x86_64 Intel:

  - iOS 13 emulator: `` (I don't have the emulators downloaded here)
  - iOS 14 emulator: `Intel x86-64h Haswell`

Feel free to update this.

Answer (score 4):

Alternative answer that is Swift Package Manager compliant:

```swift
public func getMachineArchitecture() -> String {
    #if arch(arm)
        return "arm"
    #elseif arch(arm64)
        return "arm64"
    #elseif arch(i386)
        return "i386"
    #elseif arch(powerpc64)
        return "powerpc64"
    #elseif arch(powerpc64le)
        return "powerpc64le"
    #elseif arch(s390x)
        return "s390x"
    #elseif arch(wasm32)
        return "wasm32"
    #elseif arch(x86_64)
        return "x86_64"
    #else
        return "unknown_machine_architecture"
    #endif
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I feel that this is the best answer for Swift yet:

```swift
import MachO

func getArch() -> String? {
    guard let archRaw = NXGetLocalArchInfo().pointee.name else {
        return nil
    }
    return String(cString: archRaw)
}
print("Current device architecture: \(getArch() ?? "Unknown Archetiture")")
```

For A11 (iPhone X, 8, 8+) and lower devices, the function above will return `arm64`, However for A12 (iPhone Xs, Xs Max, XR) and newer devices, it will return `arm64e`