# IS_IPHONE_5 returns 0 even if it is running on iPhone5C

Tags: ios, iphone, iphone-5, uiscreen

I have used this code to detect if the device is iPhone 5 or not to set appropriate UI.

```
( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )
```

However, it returns a 0 even if the app is running in iPhone 5c.
I also referred to  [How to detect iPhone 5 (widescreen devices)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446990/how-to-detect-iphone-5-widescreen-devices) but still the updated code doesnt work. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, at first you do also recognize iPhone5S as iPhone 5, which is not the same.
I would rather make use of the the device name, as your macros are expandable as much as you like.

```
#import <sys/utsname.h>
NSString* deviceName()
{
    struct utsname systemInfo;
    uname(&systemInfo);
    NSString *result = [NSString stringWithCString:systemInfo.machine
                                          encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    return result;
}

#define isIPhone5  [deviceName() rangeOfString:@"iPhone5,"].location != NSNotFound
#define isIPhone5S [deviceName() rangeOfString:@"iPhone6,"].location != NSNotFound
```

The list of the devices is here:

```
/*
 @"i386"      on the simulator
 @"iPod1,1"   on iPod Touch
 @"iPod2,1"   on iPod Touch Second Generation
 @"iPod3,1"   on iPod Touch Third Generation
 @"iPod4,1"   on iPod Touch Fourth Generation
 @"iPod5,1"   on iPod Touch Fifth Generation
 @"iPhone1,1" on iPhone
 @"iPhone1,2" on iPhone 3G
 @"iPhone2,1" on iPhone 3GS
 @"iPad1,1"   on iPad
 @"iPad2,1"   on iPad 2
 @"iPad3,1"   on 3rd Generation iPad
 @"iPad3,2":  on iPad 3(GSM+CDMA)
 @"iPad3,3":  on iPad 3(GSM)
 @"iPad3,4":  on iPad 4(WiFi)
 @"iPad3,5":  on iPad 4(GSM)
 @"iPad3,6":  on iPad 4(GSM+CDMA)
 @"iPhone3,1" on iPhone 4
 @"iPhone4,1" on iPhone 4S
 @"iPhone5,1" on iPhone 5
 @"iPad3,4"   on 4th Generation iPad
 @"iPad2,5"   on iPad Mini
 @"iPhone5,1" on iPhone 5(GSM)
 @"iPhone5,2" on iPhone 5(GSM+CDMA)
 @"iPhone5,3  on iPhone 5c(GSM)
 @"iPhone5,4" on iPhone 5c(GSM+CDMA)
 @"iPhone6,1" on iPhone 5s(GSM)
 @"iPhone6,2" on iPhone 5s(GSM+CDMA)
 */
```

My approach is related to the post here, but can be easily used in prefix header:
[Detect if the device is iPhone 5s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19887694/detect-if-the-device-is-iphone-5s)

---

To make sure you can use this macro in each file, follow these steps:
create a new file (lets call it "Helperfunctions")

The .h file contains the definition of the function, nothing else:

```
NSString* deviceName();
```

The .m file contains the given deviceName-code:

```
#import "Helperfunctions.h"
#import <sys/utsname.h>

NSString* deviceName()
{
    struct utsname systemInfo;
    uname(&systemInfo);
    NSString *result = [NSString stringWithCString:systemInfo.machine
                                          encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    return result;
}
```

In the precompiled header file you could add now the code (or to another file, you already imported in the .pch, so it looks like:

```
//
//  Prefix header
//
//  The contents of this file are implicitly included at the beginning of every source file.
//

#import <Availability.h>

#ifndef __IPHONE_5_0
#warning "This project uses features only available in iOS SDK 5.0 and later."
#endif

#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

    #import "Helperfunctions.h"

    #define isIPhone5  [deviceName() rangeOfString:@"iPhone5,"].location != NSNotFound
    #define isIPhone5S [deviceName() rangeOfString:@"iPhone6,"].location != NSNotFound
#endif
```

Comment: Hi. I used this in one particular controller and it works. Can you guide me on how to add it in .pch file so that I need not write it in all the screens.

Comment: Well, the precompiled header file (.pch) is used to be located in the "Supporting Files"-folder, each xCode-Project initialization sets up at the beginning. In the "#ifdef __OBJ__"-block I would add this code. Or create an file, e.g. called "Configuration.h" delete the .m-file and delete all the content from the header file and paste the above code in the Configuration.h-file. Then your .pch would look like:
#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import "Configuration.h"
#endif

Comment: Hi. I implemented the configuration file as you said. And it gives me error -
duplicate symbol _deviceName in:[80 file names]
ld: 80 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7s

Comment: Clean the build target once again and rebuild your project. Furthermore, make sure, there is no more "NSString *deviceName..." in the precompiled header file ;)

Comment: I tried that too. Still the same error. :( Will it be resolved if I add the above code in all the files that require "isIphone5" value?

Comment: No, the Macro may only be once defined, else it will be duplicated, just as the _deviceName - I think you added the device name to every header file? This may only be added once to one single header file.

Comment: No, I have just defined it in a Constants.h file and included that file in .pch file. As mentioned by you earlier. It still gives that error. Sorry for such botheration but I am a newbie.

Comment: I modified the answer, this way it should help you to access it from anywhere in your project :)

Comment: Thyank you so much for the effort. It works now. (y)

Comment: This approach is fragile, as it has to be updated every time new devices are released. If what you really want is to know whether you are on a 4-inch screen or not, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22993742/255489).

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, if you wanted something similar to what you were already doing, why not just:

BOOL iPhone5 = [[ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height >= 568 ;

Comment: I dont understand what the issue is, but its still returning 0 when I implement your code in 5c.

Comment: what does the following expression evaluate to:   "  CGFloat height =  [[ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height;   "

Comment: Surprisingly its returning 480  :O on iphone 5c and also on simulator 4 inch. :(

Answer (score 1):

Does your app have an R4 Launch Image (if you’re using an asset catalog) or a Default-568h@2x.png launch image? If not, it will think it is running on a 3.5ʺ screen no matter what device it is actually running on.

Comment: I had an R4 launch image, but the dimension was 640*1139. So I changed the dimension to 640*1136 and it worked - Ofcourse along with the above code of @Lepidopteron