# Detect iphone 6 and 6+ in simulator ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, macros, device

I am using xcode 6 and I created different xib for iphone 3.5(iphone4,4s),4.0(iphone5,5s),4.7(iphone6) and 5.5(iphone6+).
I am using this code to call the xib. This define in header file .

```
#define IS_IPHONE_5 ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )
#define IS_IPHONE_6 (fabs((double)[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height - (double)667) < DBL_EPSILON)
#define IS_IPHONE_6_PLUS (fabs((double)[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height - (double)736) < DBL_EPSILON)
```

Now in the viewcontroller file i write this method

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
if (IS_IPHONE_5)
{
    UIScreen *mainScreen = [UIScreen mainScreen];
    NSLog(@"Screen bounds: %@, Screen resolution: %@, scale: %f, nativeScale: %f",NSStringFromCGRect(mainScreen.bounds), mainScreen.coordinateSpace, mainScreen.scale, mainScreen.nativeScale);
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"ViewController_Iphone5" bundle:nil];
}
if (IS_IPHONE_6) {
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iphone6" bundle:nil];

}
if (IS_IPHONE_6_PLUS) {
    UIScreen *mainScreen = [UIScreen mainScreen];
    NSLog(@"Screen bounds: %@, Screen resolution: %@, scale: %f, nativeScale: %f",NSStringFromCGRect(mainScreen.bounds), mainScreen.coordinateSpace, mainScreen.scale, mainScreen.nativeScale);
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iphone6+" bundle:nil];
}
else
{
    //iphone 3.5 inch
    UIScreen *mainScreen = [UIScreen mainScreen];
    NSLog(@"Screen bounds: %@, Screen resolution: %@, scale: %f, nativeScale: %f",NSStringFromCGRect(mainScreen.bounds), mainScreen.coordinateSpace, mainScreen.scale, mainScreen.nativeScale);
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
}

return self;
}
```

but the problem is that when i run this app into iphone 6 & 6+ it always give the result of iphone 5.Do not call the iphone 6 & 6+ xib.
please help me..I try all the stackoverflow questions related to detect the iphone6 & 6+ but don't get the solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19887694/detect-if-the-device-is-iphone-5s

Comment: Thanks for reply but,for iphone 5 it works very well,but in iphone 6 and 6+ can not work.

Comment: Do you have launch image for iPh 6 and 6+?

Comment: NO i do not put the launch image.please help me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26141731/xcode-6-launch-image-does-not-show-up

Comment: Now You add the launchimage in your project . By this Link..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26141731/xcode-6-launch-image-does-not-show-up