# What predefined macro can I use to detect the target architecture in Clang?

Tags: macros, arm, clang

I would like to write code depending on whether the target architecture is e.g. armv7, armv7s, or arm64.

The reason that I can't use [sysctlbyname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19859388/how-can-i-get-the-ios-device-cpu-architecture-in-runtime) is that this would give me the underlying architecture at runtime, but when arm64 e.g. simulates armv7, sysctl (seemingly) still reports arm64.

Comment: Why's that a problem? 64-bit code knows it's running on v8 in AArch64 state by definition. If 32-bit code sees "arm64" or any other (inaccurate) v8 synonym then it can deduce it's running on v8 in AArch32 state. If you're not doing dynamic dispatch at runtime then your target architecture is whatever you choose to compile for.

Comment: I would like to report the target architecture.

Comment: For Microsoft Visual Studio see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37244202/detect-arm-64-in-preprocessor whose answer mentions the `_M_ARM64` defined constant beginning with VS2017.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`clang --target=... -mcpu=... -E - -dM </dev/null` will output all the pre-defined preprocessor macros (similar works for gcc, too)

I don't see single macro that provides the answer, but you can probably use some combination of `__ARM_ARCH` and `defined(__ARM_ARCH_*)`.

Comment: `__ARM_ARCH` picks up both 32-bit and 64-bit ARM machines. I believe Bram's answer is closer to the correct answer.

Answer (score 37):

Although this is not a 100% answer to the question, but may be useful:

When using clang, you can discern between 32 bit arm and 64 bit arm using:

`__arm__` which is defined for 32bit arm, and 32bit arm only.

`__aarch64__` which is defined for 64bit arm, and 64bit arm only.

Answer (score 10):

`__ARM_ARCH_ISA_A64` is predefined if it's target is arm64,

`__ARM_ARCH_7S__` for armv7s,

`__ARM_ARCH_7A__` for armv7.

Use: `clang -arch arm64 -E -dM - < /dev/null` which  can output preprocess macro.

Comment: It's the question or answer? Please elaborate.

Comment: `__ARM_ARCH_ISA_A64` is predefined if it's target is arm64. `__ARM_ARCH_7S__` for armv7s, `__ARM_ARCH_7A__` for armv7. Use `clang -arch arm64 -E -dM - < /dev/null` can output Preprocess marco, I found it in this.

Comment: @fengxing You found it in "this". Where was the source?