# How to get the iOS application CPU architecture (not device CPU architecture)

Tags: ios, cpu-architecture

What I need to accomplish is to get the architecture of the application in runtime.

Not the CPU architecture of the device, that I have. So let's say for example Xamarin iOS is supporting ARMv7 + ARMv7s but my CPU device is ARM64v8. So the Xamarin application will be running in ARMv7s, I need to have this value in runtime, is it possible?

Comment: This information should be available at compile time, so [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934862/what-predefined-macro-can-i-use-to-detect-the-target-architecture-in-clang) may apply.

Comment: Could you give an example how to use this macro __ARM_ARCH_, I can't seem to find it available.