# Detect ARM-64 in preprocessor?

Tags: visual-studio, macros, arm, 64-bit, c-preprocessor

According to Microsoft ([here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-win_upgrade/which-edition-of-windows-10-will-support-arm64/d2c3396e-3a69-40a3-a3a7-4ec7db9e5c51?auth=1) and [here](http://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2015/03/18/windows-10-iot-powering-the-internet-of-things/)), the company will support ARMv8/Aarch64 (ARM-64) in upcoming version of Windows 10. Additionally, Microsoft has [already supplied previews](http://www.zdnet.com/article/microsoft-rolls-out-windows-10-redstone-build-14267-to-fast-ring-testers/) so I'm guessing tool support is in place.

For those not aware, the [images provided with the article](http://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2015/03/18/windows-10-iot-powering-the-internet-of-things/) clearly shows a Qualcomm Snapdragon 410. That's an A-53 core, and its Aarch64/ARM-64.

Microsoft defines `_M_ARM` for ARM-32, and we currently use it to detect NEON availability. ARMv8 supports optional extensions CRC32, AES, SHA-1, and SHA-2. We have code for them written already for Apple and Linux, and we'd like to enable it for Microsoft platforms.

Microsoft also has [`__M_ARM_FP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx), but its not clear to use it to detect ARM64. I'm also not clear on the relevance of x86:

> Expands to an integer literal value indicating which /arch compiler
>   option was used:
>
> - In the range 30-39 if no /arch ARM option was specified, indicating the default architecture for ARM was used (VFPv3).
> - In the range 40-49 if /arch:VFPv4 was used.
> - See /arch (x86) for more information.

I ran some quick tests on the Microsoft compilers I have available (all of them dating back to VC++ 5.0). They failed to consume ARMv8 intrinsics, which is not surprising. I'm guessing I need a MSDN subscription to test with the latest tools, but I no longer have the subscription.

My questions are:

- How do we detect ARMv8/Aarch64 in the preprocessor (`_M_ARM64`?)
- What version of the compiler (`_MSC_VER`) support ARMv8 instructions

---

This may be related: [What is WINAPI_FAMILY_ONECORE_APP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38288622)

Comment: Intrinsics are a compiler implementation detail, nothing to do with the SDK.  Using such old compilers can't get you anywhere, VS version 15 (not VS2015) is in preview right now as well.  Do expect problems with alpha versions, report bugs and missing features to connect.microsoft.com instead of SO.  Or just wait until it is done.

Comment: @HansPassant - I'm not sure what you are talking about with respect to reporting bugs??? Its a simple question: Microsoft is supporting ARM64, so how do we detect it? Its a perfect question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: ARM64 isn't mentioned in either of those links, both say "ARM" and a max of 4GB RAM (for mobile devices) with no ARM support on "industrial" IoT editions.

Comment: @BenVoigt - ARMv8 is AArch64. It also provides an AArch32 execution environment, which is a lot like Linux multiarch and Windows on Windows (WoW64).

Comment: @jww Yes, ARM32 versions of Windows IoT run fine on ARM64 hardware, including RPi3.  But that's nothing like WOW64, it's more like x86_64 CPU mode.  WOW64 allows mismatch between application and OS but we are talking about mismatch between OS and CPU.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

VS starting from VS2017 uses `_M_ARM64`, see below for more details.

Answers, in reverse order:

- None of the currently released Visual Studio versions support ARMv8/AArch64, they only support ARMv7. Even though Windows 10 itself shows signs of arm64 support (there's some executables and libraries for arm64), none of the versions of the compiler that have been released so far actually include it, to my knowledge. (Visual Studio 2015 Community at least doesn't include it, and neither does the new Visual Studio "15" Preview 2 that was released a few days ago.) So clearly it exists internally, but it hasn't been made part of any public release yet.
- As for what define to look for; this is currently unknown, since there's no public documentation for the arm64 target version of the compiler since it's not been released yet, and one can't test empirically either.

I don't see any clear statement from Microsoft in either of your links saying that it will be supported, but at least the Windows 10 SDK does show clear signs of it being worked on.

---

Edit:

Even though the compiler isn't available, the Windows 10 SDK (which itself contains libs for ARM64) headers and Visual C++ 2015 headers (which have no matching ARM64 libs) also contains references to this. Similarly to `_M_ARM`, there's also `_M_ARM64`. A snippet from `vc/include/intrin.h`:

```
#if defined (_M_ARM)
    #include <armintr.h>
    #include <arm_neon.h>
#endif

#if defined (_M_ARM64)
    #include <arm64intr.h>
    #include <arm64_neon.h>
#endif
```

---

Edit2:

While no public version of the Visual C++ compiler targeting arm64 is available yet, clang is getting the first parts of support for Windows/arm64, and they also use `_M_ARM64`:

https://github.com/llvm-project/clang/commit/5b7d7d2b2d0bd7054f51b9d108cdd5299a0ec33e#diff-ed544af3ae6807a8513b1cabb3233941R6576

---

Edit3:

With the latest update of Visual Studio 2017, version 15.4, the ARM64 compiler is released. In the installer, one can manually check the "Visual C++ compilers and libraries for ARM64" item (it isn't enabled by default).

After doing that, you can launch "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017", and in that shell run "vsdevcmd -arch=arm64 -host_arch=amd64", then you've got the compiler in the path:

```
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt v15.4.0
** Copyright (c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community>vsdevcmd -arch=arm64 -host_arch=amd64
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt v15.4.0
** Copyright (c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community>cl
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.11.25547 for ARM64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

usage: cl [ option... ] filename... [ /link linkoption... ]

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community>
```

And this compiler predefines `_M_ARM64` which allows you to identify it, thus answering this question.

Comment: Thanks @mstorsjo. Do you have a MSDN subscription? Someone with it has access to the latest tools, and they will likely know the answer. I no longer have a MSDN subscription, so I have to ask on Stack Overflow and wait for folks with access to answer.

Comment: No, I don't have an MSDN subscription, so I can't check that, but I tested https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-next-downloads-vs.aspx which was released less than a week ago, afaik.

Comment: There's an official request for Microsoft to [add ARM64 support to Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/13362909-add-support-for-arm64), that you can upvote if you want.

Comment: This may be related: [What is WINAPI_FAMILY_ONECORE_APP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38288622)

Comment: No, that's not related. And until arm64 support is available in public versions of Visual Studio, it's really pointless to keep guessing. It simply is not available publicly yet, and those who might have early access (if any) probably aren't allowed to tell you.

Comment: with VS2017 and Win10 SDK (>=Build 15003) you can have now desktop ARM compiler: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41702306/1466046

Comment: As far as I can see in the Win10 SDK Build 15003, there's no compiler included, only link libraries, some DLLs and some tools (e.g. dxcapsviewer.exe). Those have been available for arm64 in all Win10 SDKs so far. The compiler usually doesn't come with the Win SDK, but with MSVC, and MSVC 2017 RC still doesn't seem to include a compiler for arm64, only for arm and x86/x64.

Comment: Microsoft finally documented the define. It is `_M_ARM64`. Thanks for your help.