# error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'uint32x4_t'

Tags: c, visual-studio, arm, intrinsics

I'm having trouble compiling a program under VS2013, MS2015 and VS2017 from an ARM Developer Command Prompt. According to the docs for [`<stdint.h>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/323b6b3k.aspx) and [`<arm_neon.h>`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0053c/IHI0053C_acle_2_0.pdf), the headers are correct.

What is the problem, and how do I fix it?

---

Here's the program stub. The [full program works](https://github.com/noloader/SHA-Intrinsics/blob/master/sha1-arm.c) fine under other compilers.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <arm_neon.h>

static const uint32_t K[] =
{
    0x428A2F98, 0x71374491, 0xB5C0FBCF, 0xE9B5DBA5
    /* ... more constants in real code ... */
};

uint32_t state[8] = {0x6a09e667, 0xbb67ae85, 0x3c6ef372, 0xa54ff53a, 0x510e527f, 0x9b05688c, 0x1f83d9ab, 0x5be0cd19};
uint32_t data[16] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    uint32x4_t STATE0, STATE1, ABEF_SAVE, CDGH_SAVE;
    uint32x4_t MSG0, MSG1, MSG2, MSG3;
    uint32x4_t TMP0, TMP1, TMP2;

    STATE0 = vld1q_u32(&state[0]);
    STATE1 = vld1q_u32(&state[4]);

    /* Load message */
    MSG0 = vld1q_u32((const uint32_t *)(data +  0));
    MSG1 = vld1q_u32((const uint32_t *)(data + 16));
    MSG2 = vld1q_u32((const uint32_t *)(data + 32));
    MSG3 = vld1q_u32((const uint32_t *)(data + 48));

    /* Reverse for little endian */
    MSG0 = vreinterpretq_u32_u8(vrev32q_u8(vreinterpretq_u8_u32(MSG0)));
    MSG1 = vreinterpretq_u32_u8(vrev32q_u8(vreinterpretq_u8_u32(MSG1)));
    MSG2 = vreinterpretq_u32_u8(vrev32q_u8(vreinterpretq_u8_u32(MSG2)));
    MSG3 = vreinterpretq_u32_u8(vrev32q_u8(vreinterpretq_u8_u32(MSG3)));

    TMP0 = vaddq_u32(MSG0, vld1q_u32(&K[0x00]));

    /* Rounds 0-3 */
    MSG0 = vsha256su0q_u32(MSG0, MSG1);
    TMP2 = STATE0;
    TMP1 = vaddq_u32(MSG1, vld1q_u32(&K[0x04]));
    STATE0 = vsha256hq_u32(STATE0, STATE1, TMP0);
    STATE1 = vsha256h2q_u32(STATE1, TMP2, TMP0);
    MSG0 = vsha256su1q_u32(MSG0, MSG2, MSG3);

    return 0;
}
```

And the error message is below. Lines 37-42 are the part *`/* Rounds 0-3 */`*.

```
C:\Users\Test\SHA-Intrinsics>cl.exe /DWINAPI_FAMILY=WINAPI_FAMILY_PHONE_APP msvc-arm.c
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 18.00.40629 for ARM
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

msvc-arm.c
msvc-arm.c(37) : error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'uint32x4_t'
msvc-arm.c(40) : error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'uint32x4_t'
msvc-arm.c(41) : error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'uint32x4_t'
msvc-arm.c(42) : error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'uint32x4_t'
```

VS2017 seems more broken than VS2013 and VS2015:

```
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2017 RC Developer Command Prompt v15.0
** Copyright (c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
[vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x64_arm'

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Buil
d>cd C:\Users\Test\SHA-Intrinsics

C:\Users\Test\SHA-Intrinsics>cl.exe /DWINAPI_FAMILY=WINAPI_FAMILY_PHONE_APP msvc-arm.c
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.10.24728 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

msvc-arm.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.
10.24728\include\arm_neon.h(17): fatal error C1189: #error:  This header is spec
ific to ARM targets
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue seems to be that the compiler doesn't support the `vsha256` intrinsics. If you add `/W3` to the compiler command line, you'll get the following additional warnings:

```
msvc-arm.c(37) : warning C4013: 'vsha256su0q_u32' undefined; assuming extern returning int
```

As for the VS 2017 case, something is not right in how the environment is set up/initialized, since the compiler version banner is saying:

```
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.10.24728 for x64
```

While the one actually targeting arm would say:

```
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.10.25017 for ARM
```

(I don't have that one properly installed right now to be able to help you with how to initialize the environment properly, but this was already discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/41728434/3115956. And the final release of VS 2017 IIRC did at least change something with respect to this compared to the RC which you seems to have installed, at least I remember seeing more start menu entries with the final release than what I saw in the RC.)

Comment: Thanks. I downloaded Visual Studio 2017 Build Tools again. The installer is [shows the product as a RC](https://postimg.org/image/3ki58dmuh/), and not a final release. Do you know where to find the final release? Microsoft's website is a mess and search appears to be mostly broken. Also see [Visual Studio 2017 Downloads](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017-rc) (find it under *Other Tools and Frameworks*) and the [VC++ 2017 Build Tools FAQ](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/support/#!articles/968-6900-what-do-i-need-to-do-before-installing-visual-studio).

Comment: I don't know about the plain Build Tools installer - I just downloaded the full Community edition for free from https://www.visualstudio.com. That has got a pretty flexible installer so perhaps you can choose just the build tools without getting the IDE there if you prefer that.