# How do I get the iOS device CPU type?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cpu

I need the Arm information, according to the model type from the iPhone like: iPhone 6S is "Arm64"

Here's a list of the CPUS types http://dorianroy.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/iOS_Support_Matrix_v4.1.pdf

I need this in Objective-c!

Comment: Google for a pdf2objc utility. When it fails, use your favorite editor to create an objective-c class that models this, using your pdf as source.

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19859388/how-can-i-get-the-ios-device-cpu-architecture-in-runtime

Comment: Autorealese is not available in xcode anymore...

Comment: @Giulietta Sure it is, if you were to turn off ARC for your project. Just leave out the call to `autorelease` since you are using ARC.