# C++/C Code to have different execution block on M1 and Intel

Tags: c++, apple-m1

I am writing a code for macOS application.
The application would be running on M1 based Macs as well as Intel based Macs also.
What would be the switch to differentiate M1 and Intel?

```
if (M1)
{
   do something for M1
}
else if (Intel)
{
   do something for Intel
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think, you [can use](https://blog.kowalczyk.info/article/j/guide-to-predefined-macros-in-c-compilers-gcc-clang-msvc-etc..html) `__arm__` to detect arm architecture:

```
#ifdef __arm__
//do smth on arm (M1)
#else
//do smth on x86 (Intel)
#endif
```

Comment: Note to the OP, who I suspect is under the false impression they're going to be able to do this in-code *with a single build*: you can't. The above solution will build two different versions, dependent and based on the toolchain used, the chosen target platform at build-time, and the predefined macros provided therein. The result is two different builds; one for M1 and one for anything-not-arm, and distribution of said-same to the appropriate target is on the onus of the OP.

Comment: When you archive an application, the Xcode creates a fat application or library (one executor has code for both platform). If you just build (with a run button), you will get application only for one platform (not for all).

Comment: To detect a processor name, you can use "hw.cputype", https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19859388/how-can-i-get-the-ios-device-cpu-architecture-in-runtime . But, I think, also you will want to detect emulation mode for your application: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/652667

Comment: For me, `__arm__` was not defined on my M1 MacBook Pro. I had to use `__arm64__`.

Answer (score 3):

I was just fooling around with this and found this reference for Objective-C from apple that seemed to work with clang for C++.

```
// Objective-C example
#include "TargetConditionals.h"
#if TARGET_OS_OSX
  // Put CPU-independent macOS code here.
  #if TARGET_CPU_ARM64
    // Put 64-bit Apple silicon macOS code here.
  #elif TARGET_CPU_X86_64
    // Put 64-bit Intel macOS code here.
  #endif
#elif TARGET_OS_MACCATALYST
   // Put Mac Catalyst-specific code here.
#elif TARGET_OS_IOS
  // Put iOS-specific code here.
#endif
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple-silicon/building-a-universal-macos-binary

I specifically checked to see if `TARGET_CPU_ARM64` was defined in my header.

Hopefully this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a runtime check instead of compile time check, you can think of using something like below

```
#include <sys/sysctl.h>
#include <mach/machine.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) 
{
    cpu_type_t type;
    size_t size = sizeof(type);
    sysctlbyname("hw.cputype", &type, &size, NULL, 0);

    int procTranslated;
    size = sizeof(procTranslated);
    // Checks whether process is translated by Rosetta
    sysctlbyname("sysctl.proc_translated", &procTranslated, &size, NULL, 0);

    // Removes CPU_ARCH_ABI64 or CPU_ARCH_ABI64_32 encoded with the Type
    cpu_type_t typeWithABIInfoRemoved = type & ~CPU_ARCH_MASK;

    if (typeWithABIInfoRemoved == CPU_TYPE_X86)
    {
        if (procTranslated == 1)
        {
            cout << "ARM Processor (Running x86 application in Rosetta)";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Intel Processor";
        }
    }
    else if (typeWithABIInfoRemoved == CPU_TYPE_ARM)
    {
        cout << "ARM Processor";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `#ifdef __arm64__` or `__arm64`.
Found out with the useful command

```
echo | gcc -dM -E - 

echo | gcc -dM -E - | grep -i arm
```